# C# Devexpress How to Pass Multiple Value from WinForm 1 to WinForm 2 ? (To perform New,Edit, View and so on)

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I try to pass multiple values from WinForm1 to WinForm2 (To perform New,Edit, View and so on).

WinFrom1 Name : PayrollConfigNation

DataTable :tableMaster ( bind with gridView1 )

Column Name : NationalCode - nvarchar(20),
                NationalCountry - nvarchar(50),
                GovermentCode - nvarchar(50),
                Remakrs - nvarchar(50),
                Note - ntext,
                IsActive - d_Boolean(char(1))

```
/// WinForm1 Code : PayrollConfigNation
public partial class PayrollConfigNation : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
    private BCE.Data.DBSetting mydbset;
    private DataTable tableMaster;
    private DataSet loadData = new DataSet();
    public PayrollConfigNation(BCE.Data.DBSetting DBSet)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mydbset = DBSet;
        ConfigureGridViewColumns(); // Define gridView1 column
        InitializeGridViewControl();
        LoadDataFunction();
    }
    ..........
    private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PayrollBBNationalForm myForm2 = new PayrollBBNationalForm(); 
        myForm2.Show();
    }
```

[image: WinForm1 Layout : PayrollConfigNation]
I want transfer all WinForm1(PayrollConfigNation) focused row column value (tableMaster) to WinForm2(PayrollBBNationalForm) which is the entry detail screen to perform Edit, View or even New function.

WinFrom2 Name : PayrollBBNationalForm

```
/// WinFrom2 Code : PayrollBBNationalForm
public partial class PayrollBBNationalForm : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
    private BCE.Data.DBSetting mydbset;
    public PayrollBBNationalForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

[image: WinFrom2 Layout : PayrollBBNationalForm]

I am stuck at this level, I have no idea whether should I code passing the dataSet/dataTable (tableMaster) parameter or the focus row column value parameter. I try few experiment code, unfortunately all fail so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to pass the parameter between WinForm1 to WinForm2.

I still seeking is there any better solution and nicer to code the parameter (I am still new to c# programming environment)?

winFrom1 Code

```
    int focusrow;
    focusrow = gridView1.FocusedRowHandle;
    PayrollBBNationalForm myForm2 = new PayrollBBNationalForm(tableMaster, gridView1, "New", focusrow);
```

winForm2 Code

```
    public PayrollBBNationalForm(DataTable tableMaster, GridView gridView1, String mode, int row)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tableMasterForm = tableMaster;
        gridView1Form = gridView1;
        modeForm = mode;
        rowForm = row;
    }
```